# Insert baseado em um select, com validação NOT EXISTS com múltiplos registros com PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Alguém poderia me ajudar, como faria um insert baseado em um select dessa forma verificando se o valor ja existe , com múltiplos valores ? dessa forma esta funcionando, porem gostaria de inserir mais de 1 registro de uma vez.

```
      insert into  tb_rel_regra_sit_contrato
        (
            status_acordo_id,
            sit_id,
            new_sit_contrato
        )
      sSELECT 2, 9 , 9
       WHERE  NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT * FROM  tb_rel_regra_sit_contrato WHERE
                         status_acordo_id = 2 and 
                        sit_id = 9  and
                         new_sit_contrato = 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode deixar sua query mais dinamica usando uma tabela temporaria. tipo assim:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tb_rel_regra_sit_contrato
(
    status_acordo_id int,
    sit_id int,
    new_sit_contrato int
)

insert into tmp_tb_rel_regra_sit_contrato
values(2,9,9)

insert into tb_rel_regra_sit_contrato
select 
    * 
from 
    tb_rel_regra_sit_contrato a
    right join
    tmp_tb_rel_regra_sit_contrato i
    on a.status_acordo_id = i.status_acordo_id
    and a.sit_id = i.sit_id
    and a.new_sit_contrato = i.new_sit_contrato
where a.status_acordo_id is NULL
```

Eu não sei quais são as suas chaves, então eu te aconselho mudar a query acima para fazer o join somente pelas chaves.

Comment: obrigado pela dica, adaptei sua ideia para uma Subquery e estou tentando finaliza aqui.